# Link to Deleted Questions when low rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, deleted-questions

The Team just rolled out their Recalc for everyone, and their new reputation system.  I've found that on the sites with less than 10k, the link to the deleted question isn't linked.  So right now I have no idea if they're deleting the question or the answer.  Also on a question I'd be able to go to it and see my deleted answer.

Please enable those links, and if it's the question give them the usual "You can't see this page, nah, nah, nah, nah nah" page.

Comment: I would heartily endorse changing that error page to say "You can't see this page, nah, nah, nah, nah nah"

Comment: This is planned, need to do some shuffling to support it though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with the next build, if there's a deleted answer *you can see* (you're the owner and the question isn't deleted), it'll be a link and not just a title.

Comment: Nick any plans to support this on deleted *questions* - this seems to be a rock-and-hard-place problem for new users, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148051/how-to-give-constructive-feedback-to-a-user-whose-only-question-was-deleted-with