# What do we have to do as a community to reconnect with our past?

Tags: deleted-questions, deleted-answers, discussion

I'll admit it, I have not been very active on SO for the past 18 months.  In part due to having other things that I have to get done and also in part due to the decline of feeling good about spending time on the site.  When I first started using SO, for me it was about getting help on a project I was working on.  I then started answering questions and like many really enjoyed answering as many questions as I could.  I felt good about trying to help others, watching that rep go up, and then feeling like I knew my $%^#.

Well things seemed to have changed significantly since then.  For me, SO is no longer fun.  I don't enjoy seeking help on this site.  I also don't enjoy trying to answer other folks questions.  Why?  I think for many of the reasons that the moderators are taking so much heat now. Questions and answers of mine were being dismissed left and right, while other "popular' questions that were certainly not on topic continued to linger.

Obviously things have changed in part due to the size of the community, however things seemed to have gotten worse...

For me, SO used to be fun.  SO used to be a great community to banter with other geeks.  SO used to be my favorite resource.  Why can't we simply put our energy into trying to connect with our past and what made the site so fantastic for those early users?

**What do we have to do as a community to reconnect with our past?**

**Do we even care about it?**

The infighting has go to stop as it makes the site even less fun to be around.

Comment: Is meta turning into a "My history on SO" blogosphere?

Comment: There are questions there...  But there isn't a meta - meta - meta - meta issues site yet that i'm aware of.

Comment: Could you please clarify why `SO is no longer fun`? Can you give examples of Q&A `being dismissed left and right` that are against your enjoyment? Why do you think the site was `so fantastic` back then but not now anymore?

Comment: Tom, I'm pretty sure that'd be because the reasons I listed and identified for enjoying it just aren't as valid anymore...

Comment: @TomWijsman waking up and finding that I lost 1K rep because a mod decided a question was no longer valid is certainly not fun.  Do you think that's fun? Do you think we should be happy about it?  Did that delete make the internet a better place?  Did someone looking for help suddenly find it?  (hint, answer to all questions should be "No")

Comment: The majority of SO users do not know what "the past" is, as they weren't there for it. Just keep that in mind and the know that publicly reminiscing can do more harm than good. With that said, I agree the site has gone downhill recently.

Comment: @RSolberg: Your vagueness doesn't help whatsoever. Please *add value* so that I can understand you...

Comment: @RSolberg so that I understand the statement "Questions and answers of mine were being dismissed left and right" - what questions of yours have been dismissed? Since Arpil 2010, 3 questions of yours have been closed/deleted; one was migrated to "dba", the other two you deleted...?

Comment: @JaredPar: `What career can I hope for if I like algorithms?` is off-topic and subjective at least, I don't know the actual look of that page but do you really honestly think that question actually *learned* people something and had actual value? An objective answer is actually a one liner of common sense "anything that involves algorithms", and if you want the top bill of it [here is an example job in Silicon Valley](http://www.midwestspeech.org/node/19). I don't see any learning or value involved here, just common sense and  a Google result at best...

Comment: Marc - answers, community wiki...  All combined. And not anyone single event or question stands out.

Comment: Tom - but why must those questions be dismissed? Getting search engines to get people to SO is a good thing.

Comment: Before this gets out of hand, note that this recent "thing" is something we are discussing internally later today.

Comment: Marc - I've seen lots of chatter and felt like adding some viewpoints from the good ole days might be useful. Clearly there are strong opinions that go against what SO used to operate like.

Comment: I'm afraid to post an answer because someone is probably going to come in and accuse me of treason for speaking my mind (or say I don't know what I'm talking about since I haven't been around as long as they have).

Comment: @TomWijsman you responded by not answering any of the questions I asked about your stance

Comment: There's a lot of words here that aren't really talking about *what the issue is* - so: would it be possible to summarise, clearly and succinctly, what the issue is here? is it "some mods deleted some old questions (which impacted my answers etc), without much visibility, and it has annoyed me?"

Comment: @JaredPar: I ammend: Do you think that's fun? No, we're serious. Do you think we should be happy about it? Yes, we got rid of the bad quality. Did that delete make the internet a better place? Yes, no search results that learn me nothing and were base don personal opinion instead of objective facts and references. Did someone looking for help suddenly find it? He'll find stuff that actually learns him something instead. If you can't *repeat your relatives' actions* (then you don't know what you're doing anyway), you'll start looking for *advice* and start actually ***thinking and learning***.

Comment: **Bottom line:** [I'd rather understand than upvote ponies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

Comment: @TomWijsman couldn't disagree with you more. You all have clearly lost the forest for the trees.

Comment: @JaredPar: **Quality > Quantity**. I'd rather understand how a single tree grows and dies than looking at the whole forest and having no clue what happened when the whole forest is suddenly gone; *ah, bad trees*...

Comment: They are definitely going wild deleting stuff.  Makes you wonder what will be left when they're done.  I lost 500 rep this last week (nice to finally be able to see where it went).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: And what reputation of that do you deem was on actual useful posts? Saying that you lost X reputation means nothing if the content wasn't useful. It means you shouldn't have gotten that reputation in the first place...

Comment: @Tom, I make no claim that any of it was useful, but then again I can't be sure what was deleted, because I'm under 10k and the new system only lets me see the name of the post, not go to it (even to see my own answer).  See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124391/link-to-deleted-questions-when-low-rep).

Comment: @Tom, I realize you maybe weren't around in the beginning, but there were plenty of those kind of posts then, and they were legitimate.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Sorry if you didn't claim that, it's sometimes hard to tell what thoughts you are supporting when so much comments flood in. As for your other comment, any site has to start out somewhere and the sites have improved over time. Imagine that if you don't improve upon your content and then think about what the content would have been, [*a big ball of mud*](http://www.laputan.org/mud/)...

Comment: @TomWijsman: so you're saying that the site improves by pissing off its most productive users? Isn't that *in itself* a problem? when you practically have a civil war on your hands, **doesn't that imply you're doing something wrong**?

Comment: @Tom, I'm all about improving and editing (though not so much on SO anymore for reasons I won't go into), but they had a fine mechanism of stopping new posts and locking down old posts with an inserted historical comment.  There was no reason to change that.

Comment: @jalf: Please proof to be that these are the most *productive* users? I don't see how useless posts are productive. You are all such throwing statements at us, but basing these on assumptions that aren't convincing at all...

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Perhaps, but I feel like that is for a different meta discussion. I find it reasonable to get this content out of your network, but YMMV. The community has decide on that matter...

Comment: @TomWijsman: I have around 90k rep on SO. You have 2.3k. I am one of those users. So are JaredPar, James McNellis, sbi, and many others. I count three people on page 1 of the "most active this week" users list whom I *know* agree with mr. We're not Jon Skeet, but we're productive users. Perhaps you should show us where *nothing we've posted has any value*. Because that's what you're implying. I did not earn my rep on boat programming questions, or joke threads or "what is your favorite monitor brand" question. My questions are not useless.

Comment: I hate to turn this into a rep pissing contest, but if policies enforced by users with 3k rep is alienating that many productive users, there is something wrong

Comment: @jaff: You still have 89.8k so I don't see the problem? When I mean useless I actually mean those kind of boat programming questions and joke threads, what else are we talking about here anyway? I did never state *your Q&A was useless*. I have 47.7k reputation on this whole network, and because I have not been a regular on Stack Overflow I did not magically gain tons of reputation but that doesn't mean I don't know anything here. I'm not enforcing the policy either, nor will I defend or proof it. **The whole question is making a claim that useful content is being deleted, yet I see no proof.**

Comment: @Tom: _You still have 89.8k so I don't see the problem?_ It isn't all about reputation. If jalf and other good answerers aren't _having fun_, then perhaps there is a problem to be addressed. I know there are days when I feel like [SO] is all vampires and nothing _new_...

Comment: @sarnold: Then feel free to put up a meta question about the FAQ to replace `Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.` by something by your own liking, we're here for (professional) quality instead of (useless and fun) quantity. Can you show me that a sufficient portion of the site's questions are vampire?

Comment: @Tom: I'm not at all suggesting we allow back the "useless, fun" variety of questions. Those are quite often not nearly as fun as the original questioner supposed. :) As for _sufficient portion of the site's questions are vampire?_, one just needs to look at the flag queue to see that there's plenty of rubbish: 244 flags, 146->close, 54->low quality, 31->not an answer. I don't know how to recover my own vote-to-close statistics, but I've got 558 "helpful" flags cast, and I vote to close far more often than I flag.

Comment: @Tom: But even though I vote to close piles of poor questions (and ask probing questions of most of them, the ones I think that can be salvaged), _it isn't fun_. Fun is answering the good questions. Perhaps there's not much that can be done to just have the fun, but when you hit 2.7M questions, there's going to be junk and vampires and cleaning it just isn't fun.

Comment: @Tom: It's quite possible I've got a different feeling of 'fun'. Many of these users are upset about things _on meta_ being deleted. I'd be upset too if my opinions evaporated with so little impact. On SO I don't cast _delete_ votes on questions with good answers no matter how horrible the question. But if my answers there evaporated, I'd be upset about that too. (I just don't see it often.)

Comment: @sarnold: Agreed, what one finds funny another one does not. For that reason [there are three guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) of which two have to succeed to filter out the fun that's really useless. I know that cleaning it isn't fun, even trying to debate it (but I miss any proof from the claiming party) right here isn't no fun either. I appreciate that they are upset and let us know that, but if none of these upset people show me anything *I will fail to understand why they stopped having fun*...

Comment: @Tom: The pointers from jalh and sbi are off-site because the times I've seen serious discontent raised on meta it gets vaporized a day later. Even completely pointless things, like beta UI complaints, where some people had suggested improvements with many upvotes, vaporized when "the feature was done". The discussions about that are hard to find because some of _those_ were vaporized as well. [It is very difficult to find deleted content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645) and even then, only available to 10k meta users. I'm not surprised feelings were hurt.

Comment: "I'll admit it, I have not been very active on SO for the past 18 months.", so you decided not to be part of the community for the past 18 months, and you then complain that you don't like what the community has done in your absence? "We get the government that we deserve".

Comment: Was Stack Overflow really that much more fun 18 months ago? I don't think so. You have to go back further than that to find the "good old fun days".

Comment: Related: [Why are Stack Overflow people nice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47698/2509) and [Are Stack Overflow people *still* nice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83019/2509).

Comment: @TomWijsman: yes, I have my rep. I don't see what that has to do with anything. The problem is not that a 90k rep user (taking myself as an example) suddenly no longer has 90k rep (which I do, and even if I didn't, that would be completely unrelated to what's discussed here), but that a 90k user *doesn't feel like contributing the next 90k's worth of answers*. The problem is that many users with a proven track record of making SO a much, much better site no longer feel welcome, no longer feel inclined to make SO a better site.

Comment: I have no doubt that's all you see. I think it's pretty clear by now that you see what you want to see

Comment: There's not much more than that to see! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed this as well. I came back to SO last year after a long break, to find that moderators rule the roost, pursuing a very restricted vision of what SO can be.

Now, in part the vastly expanded size and status of the site explains it - there are a bunch of people who ask terrible questions, and rules are necessary for a principled and consistent approach to discouraging all kinds of abusive behaviour.

Unfortunately, the site seems to have fallen prey to moderators-are-overlords syndrome. The rules are applied inflexibly, with strictness being an end in itself. There is no metamoderation or other mechanism to hold the moderators to account. It seems that this is how Atwood likes it, so don't expect any changes.

If you don't like it, options for change are limited. Unfortunately, I don't think anything will change until a genuine competitor is launched that addresses these issues.

Comment: Please show me that moderators rule the roost. Please show me this moderators-are-overlords syndrome. Please show me that this is the way that the valued associates like this.

Comment: "The letters of the law have become more important than the spirit they are meant to implement."

Comment: @TomWijsman: please show me that it is not the case.

Comment: @jalf: [This is a community-driven site, in which moderation starts from the users](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). This is how the network operates, you both are trying to state that this is not the case; you are the one making a statement that disagrees with existing text so you are the one that has to proof that the existing text is not the case... **Please proof his statements that tells that [this networks' written intention](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) is not true?**

Comment: @TomWijsman: it is a community-driven site, sure, the point is that "community" and "users" are not just homogenous blobs. One group of users participates in the moderation, another group does not. But the second group are still users, are still part of the community, and should still be considered and respected. The former group just fails to do so. And I think the proof is in the list I already gave you of long-time productive and prolific contributors who are alienated by MSO. But "it is written" is not proof. So where is your proof that the site lives up to its written intentions?

Comment: Helloooo? Can you see me? I'm right here, talking to you, and I am the proof. I fall in the second group. I am getting steamrollered by MSO again and again because MSO does not care about the think I care about: contributing high-quality content to SO. This thread is proof. The OP is proof. The discussion taking place here is proof.

Comment: https://twitter.com/#!/jaredpar/status/175675699422707712 and https://twitter.com/#!/JamesMcNellis/status/176084635200139264 and http://stacksbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/sbi-is-leaving/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124566/new-policy-is-draining-my-affection-for-stack-overflow is proof

Comment: My claim is simply that a number of high profile SO users are upset about the irresponsible behavior and governance of MSO. My proof is that these high profile SO users say they are upset with it. Now where is your proof that this is not the case? That we're all lying? Or that we don't count?

Comment: @jalf: None of these are SO proof. The first two Twitter comments are meaningless as a SO proof. The blog post is about meta and the meta question with 22 downvotes [has an answer with 18 upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124567/145350). I see no proof that the moderators do not listen / rule the roost / are overlords / like this, can you now please *show examples of what you or these users are upset about*? Because else I'm going to start think that you are all lying, ***make yourself count: `Learn` me that the mods are evil overlords that rule in a wrong manner and steamroll you...***

Comment: Did you check who those twitter comments are *from*? Did you bother to look up their SO profiles? I'm not sure what more I can do, if showing SO users who are unhappy with MSO is not sufficient to establish that SO users exist who are unhappy with MSO.

Comment: @jalf: Yes, I've done both but don't see anything. *Why are they unhappy?* I'm still awaiting examples, by which I mean moderator actions, not twitter statuses... You have so far ignored anything that I have asked you, because I haven't seen examples of moderator actions that shows what Marcin is trying to claim here.

Comment: @Tom: Since I must assume you can read, I can only conclude that you are deliberately trying to be obtuse. ___What about "The past deletion of my (completely appropriate!) comments on Meta is why I refuse to participate there anymore." fails to indicate that this 100k+ user has been hurt by moderation?___ And what about ___"This was removed after all this time by the arbitrary decision of a moderator"?___ Are you trying to tell us you do not understand what those users are saying?

Comment: @Tom: You asked for proof that SO users have been burned here and do not come to MSO. Jalf provides that proof. You dismiss it because you see no proof in them saying explicitly that they have been burned on meta. So I spell it in bold for you. _And now you come and ask me what I am talking about?_ And to top it all off you ask me to point out deleted comments of other people? Or are you asking about my comments I cited in that blog entry? I am sorry, but I have kids and my time is way too precious to waste on people who can't read or comprehend even when they have it spelled it to them. HAND.

Comment: @Tom: Since you do not even accept written statements of SO users that they are alienated from MSO as a proof that users got alienated, then there is no way to proof it — _to you_.

Comment: @TomWijsman What would constitute proof of users' alienation if not their own words?

Comment: @Tom: It's all there, in the links jalf provided, except for what mortal MSO users cannot access. There's all you ask for, you only have to put aside your prejudices and actually _read_ this stuff. Of course, if you want, you can also go hunting down the deleted comments of those users at MSO for yourself. `:-/` There's your proof.

Comment: @Tom: Actually, the accusation that my blog does not link to anything is completely wrong (and complaining about mere users not linking to the deleted comments about whose deletions they complain is of course utter nonsense), but never let actual facts stand in the way of your prejudices. That might have harmful effects for your peace of mind.

Comment: @Tom: We have all read many times now that you don't see proof for the alienation of users even while you are looking at it happening and can read people plainly saying they are alienated, painstakingly explaining how it happened and linking to the relevant postings. That's why I called you prejudiced; alternatively I questioned your ability to read and/or comprehend.

Comment: @Tom to suggest that sbi is immature as an argument against him, when he is concerned about the happenings on SO/MSO, is to admit that one doesn't really care if there is anything wrong going on.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Saying you don't know German, without saying that __in German__, _is just useless rant_.

Comment: @sbi: ***Spaß***... I don't care about your so-called alienation anymore, have fun deceiving yourself! *So useless.*

Comment: @TomWijsman You're actually claiming that sbi is wrong that he is alienated? You're actually playing the false consciousness card?

Comment: @Marcin: Note that we are commenting about the answer here, I wanted proof for what is being claimed. [As do ten other people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124591/what-do-we-have-to-do-as-a-community-to-reconnect-with-our-past/124600#comment334282_124600). Furthermore, [note how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124593/145350) the majority agreed with me and Sha Dow.

Comment: @TomWijsman I'm pretty satisfied that users own testimony amounts to proof. You are deliberately asking for testimony of alienation from a website that would close any such post as not constructive, and possibly delete it. You know that you are making an impossible demand.  I don't know why you are shilling for the status quo - it's not like you can get appointed to a lucrative tax collecting position.

Comment: @TomWijsman Sorry, are you responding to something that hasn't been written? sbi has posted a bunch of material, not one single blog post.  Meanwhile, you haven't addressed the point that you are refusing to accept any evidence which is available, and demanding evidence from a source that would purge any such evidence.

Comment: @Tom: It's hard to read your comments while you keep deleting them.

Comment: @TomWijsman You are now pretending that I have said things that I have not. You are also upping the threshold of proof every time, so that it can never be satisfied. I can only assume that you are merely trolling.

Comment: Speaking of studying statistics — I wonder how I managed to vote up Marcin's last comment four times. (Or did he do this himself?) And also, we managed to suppress all upvotes for @Tom. Yeah, those upvotes on comments must surely mean many people think Tom is has made very good points compared to those he argues against. And that's probably why he deleted most of his arguments: to give us a chance.

Comment: @TomWijsman Really? That's your substantive response to being called out? Pretending that you haven't been shown a mass of evidence? That sounds like...trolling.

Comment: @Tom: Proof was _in the 7th comment_ in this discussion. Since then, we just run in circles because you deny that people saying they feel alienated is proof of people feeling alienated, while others keep asking what other proof you need, to which you reply by demanding links to comments no longer existing. But, of course, it has to be those others who are trolling.

Comment: @sbi - you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.  Sometimes you just have to grab them by their head and hold it underwater until they drown...

Comment: That still aren't *real* examples or proof of events on this network but rather seem injected by a extremely small group of users, it appears that this discussion will never be useful.

Answer (score 17):

I'll share my view and personal opinion.

Stack Overflow grew up. Literally. I wasn't around when it started but I do have experience in small cozy forums where it's fun to hang around and come to know each other in the inner circle of active members. I guess Stack Overflow was like that in the beginning.

However, with never ending influx of new users joining and millions of questions asked, it could no longer stay that cozy little place. To accommodate all of this, the developers made changes not just in the look and feel of the place, but also in the rules and what's proper and what's not.

Personally I think those changes indeed saved Stack Overflow and directed it towards being a **professional** place. I also don't like seeing posts deleted with hours of efforts behind them but trust the team it's for the best - the place has changed, and there's probably no point keeping old stuff around as it's more confusing than helping.

Bottom line: Stack Overflow (and the whole Stack Exchange network) is not about fun. It should not be fun. It's a professional place for *professional and enthusiast programmers*.

Comment: *...You're kidding me, right?* If you seriously *prohibit me from having even a trace of fun*, I will gladly leave and **tell people never to come here**.

Comment: +1 **Quality > Quantity**, but let us have [fun when it gets boring](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: @Purmou here on Meta we still got unicorns and narwhals - all the fun we can get. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Doesn't seem like fun to me. Only people that have been around long enough to know what in the hell those mean can have a good laugh at them. I just play along innocently with unicorns, freehand circles, and all the other memes (which are kindly listed on that one post). So if you can suggest a way in which I can find some kind of enjoyment from these sites, please do so. Because right now *it is grim*.

Comment: @Tom this is outdated as well. The fact [war is still raging](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1995113/revisions) means Jeff own decision was overruled and though that rare "fun question" still exists, it's very likely to get deleted very soon by other moderator.

Comment: @Purmou what exactly do you want and expect?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I *want* the Stack Exchange and Meta from 7 months ago back. I *expect* nothing because the people here on Meta have nothing to do but disagree and get nowhere.

Comment: @Purmou I see and agree it won't happen but not for the reason you said - the place has moved on that's all. All the fights here on Meta, as far as I can tell, are mostly pointless - in the end of the day, the development team make all the decisions.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: That's the most edge case question that you could find. Please note that the SO community and a relatively new moderator deleted that and that that question actually contains some useful stuff which is why it reopened, see the relevant meta questions discussing it (just search for its title). Please note that it's not actually a war because it only has been deleted once, and I guess that *back then* moderators didn't care to (dis)agree with each other. Also, if you have a ton of users closing /  reopening / flagging, you get the same effect. It's mainly the users' decisions...

Comment: @Purmou: Where do you actually want to get? Because nobody here is disproving me. Actualy ShaDowWizArd tried, but that is actually not deleted right now because it does still contain useful stuff...

Comment: @Tom guess only time will tell then - that edge case reflects, in my opinion, the "fun side of Stack Overflow". :)

Comment: @Lance Tom already pointed this out and in my opinion it's outdated.

Comment: @TomWijsman should we be disproving you? Seems grandiose. We are here to discuss a question by RSolberg and an answer by Sha Dow Wiz Ard

Comment: @sehe: Or those that share my thoughts. Note though that there are comments in this whole question targeting me, most of them are just a personal statement without no proof / back-up / facts / references whatsoever. In this occasion ShaDowWizArd actually partially agrees with me, so unless someone else throws a comment towards me I don't need proof anymore for this comment thread.

Comment: @Purmou: Please take fun with you when you leave. This isn't the place for it.

Comment: I think your use of "professional" is highly misguided...

Comment: @RSolberg and why is that?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Because it implies that there is no place for fun in professionalism? That is so wrong, I wouldn't know where to start explaining.

Comment: @sbi Please start - what you have in mind?

Answer (score 13):

> Questions and answers of mine were being dismissed left and right, while other "popular' questions that were certainly not on topic continued to linger.

They are always dismissed for particular reasons, the FAQ lists some reasons *why*. As I can't see any of these I can't give you more explanation to that. But it is within good reason, most of the times...

The moderators (and other community members) are actively working against the "popular" questions problem you mentioned, this has been [brought to attention on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) and has again been [brought to attention on our meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity). When you see a "popular" question you feel don't belong here, **don't hesistate to report that as mentioned by that meta post**.

> For me, SO used to be fun.

Please read [this whole blog post on "fun"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), don't get fooled by the first part or title though.

As some parts of you questions are vague and require clarification to respond to, see my comments.

---

**Addendum:** If you feel that a "popular" question that has been deleted actually does belong here, check out whether *a community consensus* has been reached by such a meta question. If not, you can actually add to the discussion or if none exists you can post a meta question to ask the community for it to be undeleted.

So, in essence it goes both ways but the main thing to note here is that **we do try to reach a community consensus**; if you don't get enough votes gathered or don't put up a convincing proof within the time that the question reaches the required vote count, or have no way to dramatically change its directions it means that *the community has decided* and it will take you effort to change that decision.

Although contrary to what many answers and comments are trying to claim here without any proof or examples, nor the users that participate on Meta.SO nor the moderators are deciding this by their own. This site is moderated *by the community*, and if those that don't want a certain change ***don't speak up* in a way that is clear or supported by votes to us; we can't do anything for them.**

*Actions happen based on community decisions, not based on some users that cry over change...*

Comment: I think the phrase "popular question problem" is a nice summary of the disconnect here.  Meta users they are a problem, SO users don't.

Comment: @JaredPar: And why are meta users a problem? Note that SO users are tho ones who make popular questions without value. Meta.SO users try to filter these out to only get those ones that are actually useful and learn people stuff rather than some *polling for fun*...

Comment: Meta users are being a problem by spending more time on policy than actually helping people.  SO is about helping people, not establishing some grand pure question policy.  The notion of good questions has become twisted in the debates here.

Comment: @Tom: ***Please*** don't start buying into/perpetuating the idea that there are separate groups, "Meta users" and "SO users", at odds with each other.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've had a *lot* of discussions in the last few days with people on twitter, in person, here and over email. Only people who regularly participate in meta believe in the policies. It really seems like there are different ageands between SO and Meta users. We see this problem completely differently.

Comment: @JaredPar: Actually, they make sure that people don't waste their time and are actually helped in a proper way instead. Please note that I've spent my time on sites more than I did on Meta. My 47.4k network wide reputation doesn't come from nothing. The reason I'm now doing some Meta stuff is because I'm trying to help people here, at least my question is. The comments are kind of a debate simply because you have another view in your mind of which I certainly not approve. **Please share with me why you think that the deleted questions belong to that notion of good question?**

Comment: @JaredPar: For your last comment, only [a small percentage (1%)](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com) of people are regular and even a much smaller percentage of that care about keeping the quality high. You have contacted the wrong people...

Comment: @TomWijsman as I've said several times before questions should be judged by the standards of their times.  The current re-judging of questions by single mods overrides literally **thousands** of contributions by the community. It's a slap in the face to everyone who contributed.  There should be a finite window in which a deletion can occur and after that then it's a part of the history of SO and should remain there.

Comment: @TomWijsman so your argument is the small 1% who care about quality should rule over the masses who want you to stop deleting the questions?

Comment: @Jared: It's meta.***stackoverflow***. This is where you talk about Stack Overflow. It's open; it's public. I just don't understand the idea that there's some cabal trying to run SO from Meta. I don't want to lump you in with people you don't want to be lumped in with, but you and sbi and jalf and a few others have recently been posting a lot here, and your views, perhaps previously overlooked, are now being heard and considered and debated. What else can you ask for? All you have to do is speak up.

Comment: @JaredPar: Simply because these contributions are no longer useful, *please proof me otherwise*. A finite window would just allow bad quality to remain in the system...  **Please share with me why you think that the *deleted posts do not belong to the notion of being useless*?**

Comment: @TomWijsman: "SO users are tho ones who make popular questions without value. Meta.SO users try to filter these out" - ouch, ouch, just ouch

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're argument is equating public with fair.  It's a false equality in this case.  The masses who want to help people could care less about endlessly debating rules, policy and purity. The fraction of people who do care is **very** small and their opinions are dis-proportionally represented. We shouldn't have to spend time here to ensure you all aren't constantly trying to rewrite history.

Comment: @TomWijsman explain to me how deleting them makes the internet a better place?  Does deleting them suddenly cause a user looking for help to find answers?  Did it make people more likely to come to the site or more likely to stop participating?

Comment: @Jared: More to the point: I look into Meta pretty much every day, but 90% of my time on the network is on Stack Overflow. I would be extremely surprised to find (please present _data_ if you have it) that the same wasn't true of nearly every user of Meta. Meta users _are_ SO users too.

Comment: @sehe: I'm actually working further on JaredPar's incorrect assumption. Note that of my 47.4k reputation and most of my activity, the majority is not meta at all. Out of experience I can tell that these walk hand-in-hand and there are indeed no two separate groups... Don't get that comment wrong, it wasn't aimed at you two anyway.

Comment: @JaredPar: [The trouble with popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) answers all that. But here is my take on it: Deleting useless content doesn't make the internet worse. Deleting useless content doesn't waste the user his time. Deleting useless content only gets rid of those who decide to keep holding on to the useless content...  In order to disproof me, you're really going to have to answer "***Please share with me why you think that the deleted posts do not belong to the notion of being useless?***". I will ignore any other comments you make...

Comment: @Jared: This is a complex social system; there's thousands of people interacting here every day. There _are_ rules, whether they're implicit, formed by happenstance, habit, and convention -- you can call these "standards" or "etiquette" or whatever you like -- or explicitly debated and laid out. When explicit discussions happen, they happen here. That's all. (cont'd...)

Comment: @Jared (cont'd) If you live in a democracy and you don't vote, you don't get to complain about the government. If you care about how Stack Overflow works, I believe that it behooves you to keep an eye on what ***your fellow users*** are saying about that. That's the whole reason I'm here on Meta. Frankly, I'm sick of talking about this and just want to go answer some stupid ObjC questions about why adding an object to an array doesn't work (answer: the array wasn't initialized).

Comment: @JoshCaswell "If you live in a democracy and you don't vote, you don't get to complain about the government." Your idea of democracy is ***wrong***. If you live in a democracy you get to complain about the government, regardless of whether you vote or not. There are other forms of government where you don't get to complain about the government, but I doubt anyone would consider those democracies.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: where exactly does it say? And perhaps more important, isn't this rather a case of "if yuo live in a democracy, and you're not a member of parliament, you don't get to complain about the government"? That is what it looks like to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: For crying out loud, it's an analogy. Sure, you can conscientiously abstain from voting and still complain about the government. Sure, you can _in fact_ complain about your government even if you're not paying any attention to what's going on, but I don't think that you have much of a leg to stand on in that case.

Comment: @jalf: I don't understand your first sentence. For your second, my point is exactly the opposite: entry into what you consider "Parliament" here is completely open. In fact, you've joined it yourself, perhaps without meaning to. You're here, you're making your point of view known, and people are arguing with you, agreeing with you, nodding their heads, rolling their eyes, and voting your words up and down. You're participating. You're now a Member of Parliament just like the rest of us ivory-tower non-regular Meta Police elite conspiratists.

Comment: You get the 'fun' argument completely wrong.

Comment: @TomWijsman Thanks for clearing that up - I figured as much. (Perhaps we can delete these comments, so that they don't upset the conversation unnecessarily?)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: first sentence: where does it say that you don't get to complain about your government if you don't vote? Second sentence, you completely missed my point. Yes, parliament here is open, *but not every SO user is here*, just like not every US citizen runs for president. Some people have other things to do with their lives. But they're still being governed by this "parliament", and so, the parliament needs to be aware that it represents more people than just the parliament members. There's a word for a parliament which *only* looks out for the interests of parliament members.

Comment: @jalf: Not every citizen runs for president, but every citizen has the ability to write a letter to the editor, call their MP/Representative/Senator, stand on the street corner with a sign expressing their views. This analogy can get out of hand really quickly, but if one of the other things that you want to do with your life is participate on SO, and if what happens there is important to you, since you're given the opportunity to contribute to the discussion about it here on Meta, how can you reject that opportunity and still act like you're being lorded over?

Comment: @Josh: Many users who used to contribute here [ran](https://twitter.com/#!/jaredpar/status/175675699422707712) [into the hills](https://twitter.com/#!/JamesMcNellis/status/176084635200139264) [screaming abuse](http://stacksbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/sbi-is-leaving/). They've had it, and don't participate in meta anymore. However, that does not mean their views are wrong, irrelevant, and to be ignored. All it means is that the meta crowd managed to alienate a good part of SO's user base. You cannot blame them for being chased away, you have to blame yourself for doing that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: every citizen has that ability, sure, but that's still missing my point. Are you saying that a government should *only* protect those who write letters, run for president, aspire to join the government? Any half responsible government will **also** think of the silent majority, the bum on the street corner, the person who's too busy with his job, or raising her kids, or a dozen of other activities. A government which **only** thinks of those who actively participate in the governance is broken.

Comment: Since you like analogies, here's one: suppse the US government decides that all members of government should have their pay increased tenfold. Everyone in government is in favor, so it's obviously a good idea, and every should be happy. For some strange reason, a group of citizens disagree and send letters and organize protests against this. So you decide to give *them* 10 times as much money as well. Ordinary citizens who did not write letters or organize protests get nothing. Do you think that is responsible governance?

Comment: That is what you are promoting here: the belief that because everyone has the *ability* to be heard, those who don't speak up can be safely ignored. That those who choose to speak up are representative of the *entire* population. They're not. They're representative of those who choose to speak up.

Comment: @jalf: «Are you saying that a government should only protect those who write letters, run for president, aspire to join the government?» «those who don't speak up can be safely ignored.» How can the government, _itself made up of citizens_, know what those people want unless they make their views known? «Do you think that is responsible governance?» I think that's the dumbest thing I've heard all day.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: yes, I think it is dumb too. That's why it baffles me that you seem to believe that it is how Meta should work. On the off chance that you didn't mean that your opinion, as transcribed by me, was dumb, perhaps you could explain your thoughts, rather than just call it "dumb"?

Comment: @jalf: Sorry, I shouldn't have left it at just "dumb". I'm getting tired and somewhat cranky. I apologize for that.

Comment: @jalf: I'm seriously not sure what the divide here is. I understand that there's a number of people who believe that Meta represents some kind of authoritarian regime, and I don't see evidence of that. (I should note that I haven't been around as long as you and others -- I joined SO just before the "envelope kerfluffle" that sbi mentions in his blog post.) I certainly don't think that anyone should be ignored, but I don't think anyone _has to be_. I think that focusing on the "Meta Police" distracts and detracts from the serious discussion that should be happening about deletion.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: it's not an authoritarian regime in the usual sense, but it is very insular and incestuous. MSO users are great at looking out for the interests of MSO users, but tend to forget that not all SO users are MSO users as well: that the responsibility of MSO is to represent *all* of SO, not just the subset who decided to also participate on MSO

Comment: I would propose you both to continue in a chat room or stop your discussion, it's leading nowhere from an external point of view and the last comments aren't even on the topic of the question or my answer anymore. But they do only reflect the comment of JaredPar and my response to that...

Answer (score -3):

I think one thing that would serve well would be to merge the results of all the SE communities and develop settings that drive the exposure to content. Then mods can move and reassign questions to their hearts content, and it will be driven by the user what content they have access to.

Any time the deliverable determines the content the user is exposed to, the service becomes an unnatural unwanted jerk to the consumer and becomes irrelevant.

Want to stay relevant, SO? Fix this.

Comment: I think I got this exact message in a spam email once.

Answer (score -5):

### My Ideas...

1. Transparency on all moderator and admin actions for questions.

   - I actually think this is only fair to them.
   - Users believe mods are guilty without knowing any evidence or facts.  Transparency eliminates this.
2. Don't disenfranchise users

   - When people spend hours of their time answering questions, having reputation gains for that effort seems like a no brainer.  With the deleting going on, many hours have been thrown away.
3. Realize that not everything must fit into a box to have value.

Comment: Huh? #1 is already done insofar as showing which mod closed/deleted/whatever a question. If you mean "show all flags on the question", no; flags have always been private, you can't suddenly display them publicly just to deflect criticism from a mod.  We do show flags that the system is sure don't contain personal information to 10k users, which should be sufficient; I don't know what other information you're looking for. #2 is silly; spending lots of time on an answer doesn't automatically mean you deserve rep for it, especially if it's decided that the question is off-topic

Comment: #3 just seems like an attempt to add a loophole to keep questions that would otherwise be deleted; I don't even know what it's supposed to mean

Comment: Relative to #1, people will immediately assume that some backroom BS is going on when they can't see everything in one place.  They could provide a view in the dashboard showing all mod actions in one place.  Then there would never be a question.

Comment: #1 Moderating is as transparent as it can get: we have close reasons as well as people being informed of deletions, at a certain reputation you can even see deleted stuff of others (apart from comments), we have a meta where you can get clarification; we have [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) where you can actually follow the discussion by moderators (they use a separate room when they discuss user details that should be kept private) as per [this meta announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124539/a-call-for-increased-moderator-transparency).

Comment: For #3, you're damn right...  The problem is that the community believes it is either black or it is white.  If there is a tinge of gray, the phrase "GTFO" seems applied here.

Comment: Tom - where is the single view to show the activity?  Hell you don't even have a view on your own profile to show you which questions or answers of yours have been deleted...

Comment: #2 Can you give an example of this? Closing and deleting really only happens on things that are off-topic (meaning you have spent your time on the wrong site) / not constructive (it's not useful at all) / a duplicate (already been answered) / too localized (doesn't help anyone) / not a real question (ambigious / vague thus can't be answered) / old, downvoted and unanswered (because it doesn't help anyone). Looking through that, none of these involve a high amount of upvotes. And if they do, then that's merely the result of popularity BUT popularity doesn't mean research or usefulness.

Comment: #3 Please clarify what you mean by this, because that line is a good example of something that has no value. *Learn me why your statement would be valid...*

Comment: @RSolberg: Moderators usually comment with a reason, and I also believe that a message appears at the top. You would actually notice it has been deleted if you follow up on it, which you do during the time that the question is meaningful to you. **Furthermore, the reputation tab lists reputation you lost because of a question or answer of yours that has been deleted.** This has been recently implemented, reputation does not disappear magically...

Comment: One of the few answers that provided any ideas.  Apparently don't be an ass is no longer a rule... too bad...

Comment: @RSolberg: That's because the majority doesn't want to reconnect with the past. If the window in my house would've broken, I fix it, I don't throw another rock at it...

Comment: lol....  By all means, start breaking your glass...  It might take you away from your keyboard awhile longer.

Comment: @RSolberg: Are you talking to me? I think you are talking to yourself... ;)

Comment: And, ladies and gentlemen, we can see here the problem with meta: An answer suggesting flexibility and transparency  gets completely downvoted.

Comment: @Marcin: Of course, no research has been done. Transparency has been applied. Users aren't disenfranchised, I don't see any proof of that. The last point is just a quote, which is meaningless without context. This answer is not useful, and not constructive either; hence it's pretty reasonable that it has been downvoted...